Good way to understand if file has been just created rather than modified in Linux
I need a way to learn if a file has been just created (rather than e.g. modified). I do it like this:
    const bool isCreated =
            ((f.atime.tv_sec == f.mtime.tv_sec) &&
             (f.mtime.tv_sec == f.ctime.tv_sec) &&
             (f.atime.tv_nsec == f.mtime.tv_nsec) &&
             (f.mtime.tv_nsec == f.ctime.tv_nsec));

However I have just discovered that for a newly created file atime may slightly differ from mtime/ctime (nanosecond part):
# for i in {1..9} ; do echo $i; echo -n '...' > file$i; stat -c "%x %X ---  %y %Y ---- %z %Z" file$i ; sleep 2;  done

Output:
...
3
2024-07-26 11:08:49.942210415 +0300 1721981329 ---  2024-07-26 11:08:49.946210415 +0300 1721981329 ---- 2024-07-26 11:08:49.946210415 +0300 1721981329
...
Why does atime nanosecond part differ from that of mtime/ctime when a file is created?
What is a better way to distinguish between a situation when the file has been created rather than modified?

Try touch file$i. This way there shouldn't be any delay between creation (which happens when file handle is opened) and content write (because touch won't write anything).

The file has been modified (as you wrote in it since its creation), so the corresponding time stamps (mtime/ctime) changed accordingly.
